# Computing cyclic cubic splines

Tags: interpolation, spline

Cubic splines (piecewise interpolator with $C_2$ continuity) are well-known to be computable from a tridiagonal system of equations that give estimates of the second derivatives at the interpolated points.

Different endpoint conditions are allowed, such as *natural* or *constrained*. The resolution is easy and fast.

The cyclic case (equal derivatives at endpoints) is more difficult, as the matrix is cyclic-tridiagonal (nonzero coefficients in the corners). Despite Web search, I didn't find a clear explanation of the modified resolution in this case.
Can you help ?

Comment: Do you have problem in interpolating points with a periodic B-spline or you have problems because the matrix is no longer banded?

Comment: @fang: no longer banded (but close to). It is not B-splines but cubic splines.

Comment: Maybe it's my ignorance, but what makes you expect cubic splines to be easier to compute than solving cyclic-tridiagonal systems?

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson: not easier, in fact harder, because you can do without an explicit storage of the matrix and compute the coefficients on the fly.

Comment: If you are asking about solving a cyclic tridiagonal system, see [this](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10137/solving-system-of-linear-equations-with-cyclic-tridiagonal-matrix).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: that's interesting, thank you. I must admit that since I posted, I have tried different solutions and still miserably failed. The main difficulty is that I want to keep $O(n)$ storage and I stumble on corner cases.

Comment: You just have to store one element for the last row (there is a nonzero introduced by Gaussian algo, but removed by the next loop), and a vector for the last column. But that's assuming there is no singular submatrix (that is, you don't need pivoting), and I'm not sure it's guaranteed: it is ,for instance, if the matrix is strictly diagonally dominant.

Comment: There is also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm#Variants), but I have never implemented this approach.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: by linearity, the periodic case can be indeed solved by superposition of two non-periodic problems, then finding the appropriate superposition coefficients. This is an attractive approach as it reuses the standard algorithm (which I have), but I also failed to finalize the details.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: I should add that I based my implementations on the code in Numerical Recipes, the formulation of which slightly differs from the standard presentations for optimization reasons. Hence problems with the adaptations to the period case.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't looked at that case specifically, but Wilf's ["generatingfunctionology"](https://www.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/DownldGF.html) (available for free at the link) gives a delightful treatment of cubic splines using generating functions to solve the equations. Worth a read.

Comment: Mh, all I found in this text is "Hence it remains only to solve the equations (1.4.8)." where the equations are the tridiagonal system.